# Converting (Maybe a, b) to Maybe (a,b)

Tags: function, haskell, tuples, type-conversion, option-type

Is there an easy (without reinventing the wheel) to convert from `(Maybe a, b)` to `Maybe (a,b)`. I looked at `Traversable` but can't make it work.

Comment: Using `-XTupleSections` you could do something like:  `f (x, y) = (,y) <$> x`.

Comment: *"Without reinventing the wheel"* and *"easy"* are very vague terms. To an experienced Haskell programmer, maybe concepts that are difficult for a beginner maybe be very straightforward. Could you redefine what you mean?

Comment: "without ..." I mean not rolling out my own function, but using a function which already exists . "easy" : usable as such in a expression. Petr `bitraverse` solution is a good example of it. My solution using sequence `fmap swap . sequence . swap` doesn't reinvent the wheel but it's not what I qualify easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use [`Bitraversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-4.1.1/docs/Data-Bitraversable.html):

```
bitraverse id pure :: (Bitraversable t, Applicative f) => t (f c) d -> f (t c d)
```

which specializes to

```
bitraverse id pure :: (Maybe a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Functors.

```
solution :: (Maybe a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
solution (a, b) = fmap (\q -> (q, b)) a
```

Or, in pointfree style:

```
solution = uncurry $ flip $ fmap . flip (,)
```

Additionally, as @Bakuriu said, if you have `TupleSections` enabled, and `Control.Applicative` imported, it becomes *really* easy:

```
solution (a, b) = (, b) <$> a
```

Learn more [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

Answer (score 3):

The following works with [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens):

```
> import Control.Lens
> _1 id (Just 1, 2)
Just (1, 2)
```

Comment: Note that this is the same as `sequenceAOf _1 (Just 1, 2)`. I guess it's personal preference which one you prefer.

Comment: I like that lots, even though it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by “without reinventing the wheel”? The most straightforward way to create such a function is as follows:

```
f :: Maybe a -> b -> Maybe (a, b)
f Nothing  _ = Nothing
f (Just a) b = Just (a, b)

g :: (Maybe a, b) -> Maybe (a, b)
g = uncurry f
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I mean , I can write as it's pretty straight forward indeed, but I was wondering if such function already existed as it looks to be a specific case of the more general `(m a, b) -> m (a,b)` or even `t (m a) -> m (t a)`